# UPML and tensor multiplication?

Tags: simulation, electromagnetism, crystal

I am studying uniaxial perfectly matched layers.

In order to absorb outgoing waves we introduce a tensor S (I have anderstood how it is calculated)
\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{s_y s_z}{s_x} & 0 & 0  \\
    0 & \frac{s_x s_z}{s_y} & 0  \\
    0 & 0 & \frac{s_x s_y}{s_z} 
\end{bmatrix}

and to use PLM we incorporates S in this way

$$ \nabla \times \vec{E} =  [\mu_r][S] \vec{H} $$

and a similar thing for other Maxwell equations.

I don't understand why we can simply multiply S with the permeability tensor.

A reference:

https://empossible.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Lecture-3c-Perfectly-Matched-Layer.pdf

page 17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will preface this with a disclaimer that I am not familiar with the concept of a UPML, but I may be able to shed some light on the 'why'.

One way we could think about why we are 'allowed' to simply multiply it into the equation is that it is unit-less, and therefore will have no affect on the unit/dimensional analysis of the expression, and will simply act as a scaling factor.

However, the reason we are doing this is a little more subtle. When EM waves propagate, they do so either through a physical medium or a vacuum. When we use Maxwell equations in a vacuum, it looks similar to your equation you provided, but without the [S], and we dont use relative permittivity/permeability but the free space value. When we use maxwell equations inside a material, we see that a relative permittivity/permeability value is used instead, that can be considered a scaling of the free space value. This is our first clue for what S might be doing, and why it is allowed to be there.

If I am understanding the purpose of a UPML accurately, it tries to provide a conceptual boundary to a space which will absorb any wave incident at the boundary of the simulation/space/problem. If we placed something 'real' here like a wall, then this may have a different relative permittivity/permeability than the area inside the simulation, and since they are different, there will be reflections on the boundary. (snell's law, total internal reflection etc) What UPML seeks to do is to perfectly size the relative permittivity/permeability so that the wave is fully absorbed without reflecting anything back (which would interfere with the simulation results).

S is effectively just a scaling factor for the relative permittivity/permeability value. And since relative  permittivity/permeability is a very common occurrence to be included in Maxwell equations (for any situation where the waves are propagating through anything other than a vaccuum), it shouldn't be too much of a leap to see that this is a procedure which is allowed.

Granted, this might be completely wrong, so if anyone has better knowledge please do correct me!